# How can I adjust this query to produce a result that shows the average on a month-by-month basis over time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a hard time producing the desired result with one of my queries.

I'd like to be able to display the average revenue generated per user on a rolling month by month basis, based on the following criteria:

- User must belong to a particular cohort, defined as a user who has booked more than 20 times in the last 90 days (so, for example, a user only gets counted in the January cohort if they have booked more than 20 times across the months of November, December and January)

The below query is what I have now, which pulls the average revenue per user for the January cohort:

```
WITH bookings as (SELECT u.id as user_id, count(*) as bookings_last_90, sum(total)/100 as revenue_last_90
            FROM revenue r
            JOIN users u on r.user_id = u.id
            WHERE (CAST(r.created_at AS date) BETWEEN CAST((NOW() + INTERVAL '-90 day') AS date)
                AND CAST(now() AS date))
            GROUP BY u.id 
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20)
SELECT avg(b.revenue_last_90)
FROM bookings b;
```

I essentially need to adapt the above query to pull the average revenue per cohort user on a rolling month by month basis, keeping in tact the past 90-day timeframe for cohort definition.

Comment: You should illustrate your question with the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach when you've got a query that works with one timestamp is:

1. Generate a list of dates or timestamps to use in a table, view, CTE, etc
2. Join to the list of timestamps
3. Replace the timestamp you're using with the timestamp from the list

With no schema, I can't test it, but the results may look something like:

```
WITH --first generate list of dates from the created_at field in revenue
month_list as (select date_trunc('month' , r.created_at) as m from revenue r group by 1 )

--then use that in the bookings query
, bookings as (SELECT u.id as user_id, m.m as cohort_month, count(*) as bookings_last_90, sum(total)/100 as revenue_last_90
            FROM revenue r
            JOIN users u on r.user_id = u.id
            join month_list m on r.created_at between m.m + interval'-60 day' and m.m + interval'1 month'
            WHERE true
            GROUP BY u.id , m.m
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20)

--finally, use the date in the result query
SELECT avg(b.revenue_last_90), cohort_month
FROM bookings b group by cohort_month;
```